# Null reference exception for existing but encrypted query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, query-string, nullreferenceexception

I face the following problem :

I encrypt my query string then encoding the result so i get `url` like this :

---

```
PageDetail.aspx?enc=LFgzoz6LxQ54RaOMuZCJlluim9oH%2fRW2bpGJEo3rZ7E1Y8ixg9vbHRRc2koFdqbK%2f5PS%2fIv1v%2b3N%2beLwXJMtpdTOEwqwZLoTkh%2bIPW1S4f4764i3MY%2f9AECdSNmIgeaSovpJouXp3bQi4ntOyJOzW4eXawpAvS3gGvPWQLsr0My9NcAd5PT5Qwr2vVOfzjAYc%2f%2f1AdseguQUyWX7sIPK%2fPGYxLmjU204I2bGS%2f8%2fSPCXp4fZfbfJIaafBmSFbRhXAb%2fneWQFb83PzcP7Ljk9o90qMAeVuRvwhAcy6IsPmW76OpwT8JRK8Vw%2fTrmoSDmNCMYN1VuCm%2fT6fvg1mbiruqmPnDoKXr8zR2ChY1zev8leWHWPDmn572Hi02w6nu4vamOSlgIvH2LNEHUYYtIITX1DH%2bSagIl%2fuiNtWsQsdrqd%2b31ksO8GVYuJcAnn7%2fcST4w5Fzs3JPO2cPwiMeXDQw%3d%3d
```

---

Then i try to decrypt the result :
but when i try to get the query string through :

```
Request.QueryString["enc"]
```

I get null reference exception i don't know why?

Comment: It might be possible that you are attempting to access the Request object at a point in the page lifecycle when it doesn't yet exist or has been destroyed.

Comment: I encrypt in the a page called `items.aspx` then when click on the encrypted link i try to decrypt in the page load of `PageDetail.aspx`

Comment: can you post stack trace? or try Request["enc"].

Comment: I get the same exception :

`at UI.PageDetail.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in F:\...\UI\PageDetail.aspx.cs:line 29
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line of code will not throw a null reference exception because it can't find the querystring part but because it can't find the Request object. The QueryString part will just return null if the part you are looking for doesn't exist.

Likely this is because this code is being written somewhere where the Request object hasn't been set up (eg application start event). You'll need to most likely move the code somewhere more suitable. If you believe that you should be able to access the Request object from where you are then you will need to provide us with more details of the context of that line of code.

Comment: `Request.QueryString["enc"]` in the page load of `PageDetail.aspx`

Comment: before I made the encryption, i could reach the query strings !!

Comment: There is only one line of code in your question. I meant that one.

Comment: Also If a change you made causes it to go wrong you should include that sort of information in the question. I had no idea that it worked before because you didn't tell me. If it is as you said then my guess is that its not actually that line of code that throws the exception or there is more on that line of code than merely assigning `Request.QueryString["enc"]`.

Comment: Hmmm... And is the downvoter still around to explain the problem with my answer?

Comment: @just_name: Thanks. I didn't think it would be you but I like to know if somebody downvotes an answer why they are doing it so that I can improve suitably (or so I can educate them on why they are mistaken if appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

Your argument in query string has 514 chars, a think that it could be cause of problem.
 Query string has limit of its lenght.

Comment: hmmm, then how to minimize the length, just i make encryption then encoding  , and i want to decrypt the querystring !

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work, but you can try compress your query string with any lossless compression algorithm.

Comment: @Jacek: In general strongly encrypted stuff appears random which means that compression (which relies on patterns) can't really do much with it.

Comment: @just_name: You might need to step the problem back and examine whether encrypting the querystring is actually the right solution. If you are encrypting what goes in the querystring server side then you could just store the data in it and put some kind of short ID in the querystring. If it is being encrypted on the client then it may not be secure.